# Proof from text book PDE 4th Edition by Fritz John

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Please help.

Using a Taylor Series expansion about $(x-ct)$, prove that:

\begin{align}
\lvert u(x, t + k) - (1 - \lambda c) u(x, t)- \lambda c u(x - h, t) \rvert &= \lvert f(x - ct - ck) - (1 - \lambda c) f(x - ct) - \lambda c f(x - ct - h) \rvert \\
&\leq Kh^2
\end{align}

Where $u(x, t) = f(x - ct)$, $\lambda = k/h$ and $K = \frac{1}{2}(c^2\lambda ^2 + \lambda c) \sup \lvert f" \rvert$

This problem is from the text book by Fritz John, 'Partial Differential Equations', 4th Edition, page 7.

I know that by using Taylor Series expansion about $(x-ct)$ in second derivative :

$f(x-ct-ck)=f(x-ct) + \frac{f^{'}(x-ct)}{1!}(-ck) + \frac{f^{"}(x-ct)}{2!}(-ck)^2$

But I do not what to do next.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When asking a question, it's better if you include what you've tried (even if you've got no idea where to start!), so that the people who answer don't reiterate thoughts that you've already had.

Comment: Thank you. I just edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have after the expansion
\begin{align}
&\lvert u(x, t + k) - (1 - \lambda c) u(x, t)- \lambda c u(x - h, t) \rvert \\ &= \lvert f(x - ct - ck) - (1 - \lambda c) f(x - ct) - \lambda c f(x - ct - h) \rvert \\
&=\color{red}{f(x-ct)} + \color{blue}{\frac{f^{'}(x-ct)}{1!}(-ck)} + \frac{f^{"}(x-ct)}{2!}(-ck)^2\color{red}{-(1-\lambda c)f(x-ct) \\-\lambda c f(x-ct)} \color{blue}{-\lambda c \frac{f^{'}(x-ct)}{1!}(-h)} -\lambda c \frac{f^{"}(x-ct)}{2!}(-h)^2 
\end{align}
where the red terms cancel each other and the same for the blue terms if we use $\lambda=k/h$. Then you can use that $f''(x-ct)\leq \sup_z |f''(z)|$.

Comment: Thank you for your help.